# How to add a recurring Interest rate onto a recurring and growing amount

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the given percentage onto a number repeatedly over a few months that already has the percentage added on from the previous month.

I.e, The user defines 25% (this is not set could be any number of percent) I then add 25% onto the amount they invested to start with, for example:

Customer invests £10,000, I add 25% onto £10,000, which equals £12,500. **AND THEN** the following month I add the 25% onto the £12,500 from the month before, which should equal £15,625.

It should be a case of simple maths, yet i cannot figure this out using Javascript. I keep getting the value of £15,000, and cannot work out how to store the given percentage in a variable itself and then add that percentage onto the Total amount.

Here is some code.

```js
// Set the values...
  Num = prompt("Enter a percentage using a decimal Number...");
  interestRate = Num*100;
  startCash = 10000;
  total = startCash*interestRate/100+startCash;
  month = 1;
  
  // Inputting Text...
  StartText = "Starting Money: £";
  IntText = "Interest Earned: ";
  TotalText = "Total Amount: £";
  MonthText = "Month: ";
  
  displayStart = StartText + startCash + "\n";
  dispInt = IntText + interestRate + "\n";
  dispTotal = TotalText + total + "\n";
  dispMonth = MonthText + month + "\n";


  dispvalue = displayStart + dispInt + dispTotal + dispMonth;
  


  console.log (dispvalue);

  addInt = total + interestRate*100;

  console.log (addInt);
```

Comment: compound interest can easily be done by reducing

Comment: Redu, I don't understand what your trying to say buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try an approach like this:

```
var interestRate = .25;

var startCash = 10000;

var total=startCash;

for(var monthCount=1; monthCount<13;monthCount++){

    //this line takes the previous value of total and gets the percentage of interest
    //it is then re-assigned back to the same variable
    total += total*interestRate; 

    console.log('month :', monthCount);
    console.log('total :', total);
 }
```

Comment: The line total += total*interestRate; Lead me to the overall outcome i have been trying to achieve for a few days now. I modified it to this, addInt = total*interestRate/100 and then added at the bottom of my loop total += addInt, now my loop displays and updates the months from 1 -12 and adds the Interest to the previous months total. Excellent thank you

Answer (score 1):

The total from compound interest calculated for the next month should be

```
addInt = total*interestRate/100 + total;
```

just like the fifth line of your code.

Comment: Also, see [this Wikipedia page for the calculation of compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation_of_compound_interest)

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows;

```js
var interest = 0.25,   // monthly interest
      curVal = 10000,  // current value
    duration = 12,
         sum = Array(duration).fill(interest)
                              .map((c,i) => curVal*Math.pow(1+c,i));
console.log(sum);
```

Every start of month we are calculating the compound interest and applying it to the face value which is 10,000.

Comment: explaining what the code actually does would be useful for learning purposes. :) Also, does this work? When I copy it and use his values...it doesn't yield the same result.

Comment: @E. Maggini I will modify my code to include explanation. But my interest is 12.5% annual which is not the same. Will correct that too...

Comment: I really like your code because I am pretty code at javascript and I don't full understand how yours works.  I am going to have to research .fill and .map :)